# SQL Server 2000 trigger on insert

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I need to create a trigger for my table that will contain millions of inserts.

That trigger will send an email (already done) to me saying that table is being powered.

That email should be send only once when the insert starts (one a day).

In other words, I wanna do this :

```
Create trigger on table T1 on FIRST INSERT; EXEC my procedure to send email
```

Not being a developer I really don't know how to write this...

Thank you for you help.

Comment: You cannot have an `ON FIRST INSERT` - either it's on **ALL** inserts, or on nothing.

Comment: If you want to use email, then I assume that your requirement is not to know precisely when the first `INSERT` happened, but rather to know that your load process has started. If so, you could create a SQL job that runs every 5 minutes and checks if there are new rows in the table (how you do that depends on the data). If there are new rows then send the email, otherwise do nothing. Even better would be to build the notification into the load process itself, but I assume it's outside your control or you wouldn't need this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot easily do a `ON FIRST INSERT` trigger.

What you could do is this:

- create a normal `ON INSERT` trigger that sends you the email
- at the end of that trigger, disable that trigger:

  ```
  ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable DISABLE TRIGGER YourTriggerNameHere
  ```

This would prevent the trigger from firing over and over again and sending you tons of e-mail.

Then, you'd also need a SQL Agent job that would at night enable that trigger again - so that it could fire again for the first insert of the next day.

**Update:** OK, so in your case it would be:

```
CREATE TRIGGER sendMail 
ON MyTable AFTER INSERT 
AS 
    EXEC master.dbo.MyProcedure 

    ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable DISABLE TRIGGER sendMail
```

and in your SQL Agent job at night, you'd need:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable ENABLE TRIGGER sendMail
```

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking about. It's done once a day but I don't know if it's possible to enable and disable a trigger...

Comment: So my script would be like this (plz correct me if I'm wrong):

CREATE TRIGGER sendMail
ON MyTable
AFTER INSERT
AS
EXEC master.dbo.MyProcedure
//HOW TO DEACTIVATE IT ?

Comment: @user2076126: updated my answer with detailed instructions on how to disable and re-enable the trigger

Comment: A question had come to my mind :)))
If my trigger can't work : the EXCHANGE server for example is down and can't send emails, will it affect the insertions in my table ?

Comment: it just send an email to me saying that the process has started nothing more... So if it hangs (email server) the process will stop ?

Comment: @user2076126: unless you've done something to call it asynchronously - yes, most likely it will hang (until a timeout occurs)

Comment: Thanks for your help marc. I think I'll pass this solution for now. Your help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Why not have a table that you also update in your trigger with the last time that an email was sent out? Then you could query this table in the trigger and decide whether you want to send out another on

```
create trigger tr
on tab after insert
as
begin
    declare @today datetime;
    set @today = cast(convert(varchar(32), getdate(), 112) as datetime);

    if not exists(select * from logtab where logdate = @today)
    begin
        -- Send the email
        exec sendMail

        -- Update Log Table
        update logtab
            set logdate = @today
    end
end
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant directly fire a trigger on first update.

You can however have a table that log when you send emails and for what table, and in the trigger you can ask if there is a record there for that day dont send it, if its not, insert in that table and call your sp.

Your sp could do this check also.